# How can I dynamically add fields to a widget's options?

Tags: custom-options, widget-instance

I am creating a standard Magento widget. In the options tab for the widget I have a field. This field is for filters in the form of `key:'value'` pairs. I would like the user to be able to dynamically create as many filters as they need.

So, ideally the user clicks a button 'Add new Filter' and a new field is generated below the original field.

[image: widget options]

I have an idea that I can use a custom `<source_model>`, but I am not sure what javascript methods or Mage classes already handle dynamic buttons such as this. I'm thinking there has to be an easy way.

My widget.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <widgets>
      <namespace_module type="module/links">
        <name>Widget Name</name>
    <description>Display a gizmo</description>
    <parameters>        
      <filters>
        <label>Filters</label>
        <visible>1</visible>
        <required>0</required>
        <type>text</type>
        <source_model>module/filters</source_model>        
      </filters>
    </parameters>
    </namespace_module>
    </widgets>
```

Then I have `app/code/community/Namespace/Module/Model/Filters.php`

which looks like:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Filters {

  public function toOptionArray() {
    return array(
      array('value' => 'val', 'val' => '1'),
      array('value' => 'val2', 'val2' => '2'),
      array('value' => 'val3', 'val3' => '3'),
    );
  }

  // Can I do anything here to generate dynamic fields?

}
```

Perhaps this is not the correct way to go about this? Is it possible to create a custom `<type>` and generate the buttons there? Maybe I just need more coffee `["])`

**UPDATE:** I'm now looking at the `<type>multiline</type>` parameter, to see if I can use that. However, I think I'm still going to need to create a custom multiline. The reason is that `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Multiline` has the line count hardcoded:

```
public function __construct($attributes=array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->setType('text');
        $this->setLineCount(2); // hardcoded
    }
```

Comment: The user must be able to click a button 'add new field', which generates a new field and updates the <line_count> attribute, which is currently hardcoded in core.

Comment: Well, looks like it's going to be wasted bounty.

Comment: yes u may need some more coffee and also increase the bounty to attract someone to help you :)

Comment: Maybe it's the lack of coffee again (lol), but I cannot seem to figure out how to award more bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not got much experience with widgets, but if this works like any other admin panel form you could make use of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract` and store your filters as a serialised array?

Have a look at `Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Minsaleqty` for an implementation of it.

It should allow you to add dynamic rows and store them all under one serialised attribute, kind of like how this picture shows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Luke! It seems Magento widgets don't behave like most admin panels, however the block you quoted is certainly valid as that is where I was monkeying around in the beginning. I'll delve into this some later today and let you know my results.

Comment: Good luck! These array inputs are a bit of a paint, just have a delve through how they're implemented in the core and try and recreate.

Comment: I haven't put it together yet, but briefly looking I'm positive you've provided the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, good luck with the implementation. The render for these array inputs are a massive pain, but should definitely allow you to do what you want!

Answer (score 2):

I needed exactly this function and came up with my own widget extension. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/mageprofis/MageProfis_WidgetArray). But for the impatient here's how to use it:

In your `widget.xml` you can use this extension as a helper block:

```
<!-- Widget XML definition -->

        <items>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <label>Items</label>
            <type>array</type> <!-- Use "array" type -->
            <helper_block>
                <type>mp_widgetarray/adminhtml_widget_array</type>
                <data>
                    <columns>
                        <text translate="label">
                            <label>Text</label>
                        </text>
                        <col2 translate="label">
                            <label>Col 2</label>
                        </col2>
                        <!-- Add more columns as needed. -->
                        <!-- Node name will become field name. -->
                    </columns>
                </data>
            </helper_block>
        </items>

<!-- Widget XML definition -->
```

The values are stored as a base64 **AND** json_encoded string, so in your widget block class you need to use `base64_decode` and `json_decode`.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Widget_YourWidget
extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        $b64 = $this->getData('items');
        $json = base64_decode($b64);

        return json_decode($json, true);
    }
```

This will yield something like this:

[image]